# dvswitch, v4l2loopback and gst-launch to v4l2sink give too high framerate

Tags: avconv, gst-launch

I'm testing two webcams with dvswitch:

```
dvswitch -h localhost -p 2000
```

using avconv to generate dv streams, piping them to dvsource-file:

```
avconv -y -f video4linux2 -s 640x480 -r 15 -i /dev/video0 -f s16le -ar 48000 -ac 2 -i /dev/zero -target pal-dv - | buffer -u 100 | dvsource-file -h localhost -p 2000 /dev/stdin
```

(command for only one webcam, using buffer command because named pipe gives bad results)

I can see and do picture in picture with the two sources in dvswitch gui with no problem at all. I can also use dvsink-command to catch the dvswitch generated stream and pipe it to gst-launch pipeline with a v4l2sink output:

```
dvsink-command -h localhost -p 2000 -- gst-launch -v fdsrc fd=0 ! dvdemux ! dvdec ! tee name=t_vid ! queue ! v4l2sink sync=false device=/dev/video2
```

(tryed also with "v4l2sink sync=true device=/dev/video2"...)

and opening the /dev/video2 with vlc show up the dvswitch generated video:

```
vlc v4l2:///dev/video2
```

but ekiga, skype and also xawtv crash when they try to open the video2 loopback device!

using vlc "tools -> codec information" menu, I see "packed yuv 4:2:2 (yuy2)" with the correct resolution but with a framerate of over 4.200 (over 4 times 1.000...), even if the video show up at normal speed.

I think vlc and (xvimagesink of gst-launch) can display video from this virtual device, but ekiga et al are not able to do so becasue the framerate very big and strange number...

any idea on reducing the framerate to something like 15 or 30 fps? I tried with some gst-launch pipelines with videorate, but with no luck.

many thanks,

francesco

Comment: I'm running ubuntu 12.04, with kernel 3.2 and v4l2loopback, dvswitch 0.8.3, avconv 0.8.10, gstreamer 0.10 and vlc 2.0.8

Comment: Often you can control the framework with a caps filter like `... ! 'video/x-raw, width=1280, height=720, framerate=30/1' ! ...` but I don't know if that will work here.